# How to distribute Java3d jar files with netbeans dist?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java-3d

I have a java project on netbeans (Mac OS X) that uses `Java3d`. On the mac version of java distribution, java3d is already included. However now I want to distribute my application as `jar` for other platforms. When I `Clean and Build` the project in netbeans it generates the `dist` folder as the follow:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── AbsoluteLayout.jar
│   ├── jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar
│   └── swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
├── README.TXT
└── MyApp.jar
```

But as you can see it has not included any jar file related to java3d. How can I force Netbeans to include necessary jar files to my distribution folder?

#### Update:

On a second try, I downloaded java3d from Oracle website and extracted everything until I found three java3d related jars. However adding them to the project causes an error in Ubuntu when I try to run `java -jar MyApp.jar`:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path
```

This software is targeted for several platforms and I want my users to be able to run it by simply executing the jar file without getting involved in any technical issues. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are native libraries involved here.  This won't be easy; maybe impossible.

Netbeans won't help your users.

Perhaps you can script some setup commands to create the appropriate environment variables, then call the executable JAR.

You'll have to create different versions of the script for *nix and Windows.

You'll need to package everything in a ZIP file that arranges the artifacts as needed or write an installer to help.

Comment: The whole idea of the question was to avoid this process but at the end I think I have to do as you said.

Comment: I don't know of a way to avoid this process.  If those native libraries are called, you are obligated to provide them.